# How to use Electron BrowserWindow in React Typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

I am currently trying to find a way to integrate third-party URLs, such as disney+ or spotify, into my application. I quickly found out that it's not possible with `iframe`, since many sites are blocking it. My next idea was to use `Electron's` `webview` tag. However, this has been depreciated.

Now I have the idea to integrate Electron's `BrowserWindow` into the React Dom.
So basically, to write an `electron React application`

https://medium.com/folkdevelopers/the-ultimate-guide-to-electron-with-react-8df8d73f4c97

If I follow this guide and import everything, I get this error.

```
App.tsx:2 Uncaught TypeError: window.require is not a function
```

I know it is typescript .. require ... not a solution. But import is not working as well. I also tried to built an normal javascript application just to test it, but that did not work as well.

I'm also convinced that even if I get the import right, I should get a `constructor error`. Does anyone have experience with this problem and could please help me.

electron main.ts

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import * as path from 'path'
import installExtension, {
  REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS,
} from 'electron-devtools-installer'

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      // contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  })

  if (app.isPackaged) {
    // 'build/index.html'
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/../index.html`)
  } else {
    win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/index.html')

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Hot Reloading on 'node_modules/.bin/electronPath'
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
      electron: path.join(
        __dirname,
        '..',
        '..',
        'node_modules',
        '.bin',
        'electron' + (process.platform === 'win32' ? '.cmd' : '')
      ),
      forceHardReset: true,
      hardResetMethod: 'exit',
    })
  }
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // DevTools
  installExtension(REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS)
    .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
    .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err))

  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit()
    }
  })
})
```

App.tsx

```
import './App.css'
const electron = window.require('electron')
const remote = electron.remote
const { BrowserWindow } = remote

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>halllo</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          let win = new BrowserWindow()
          win.loadURL('https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote')
        }}
      >
        Open BrowserWindowss
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

react tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "../build", // Output transpiled files to build/electron/
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in main.ts :

```
 webPreferences: {
   nodeIntegration: true,
   contextIsolation: false,
   enableRemoteModule: true,
   preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this and it works OK:

- [Create a desktop app with Electron, React and C#](https://itnext.io/create-desktop-with-electron-react-and-c-86f9765809b7)

It uses `require` in `main.ts` but uses `import` in the React code.

Its using `import` means that the required module is included into the renderer bundle at build-time by Webpack, instead of loaded at run-time from thee `Node.js` environment.

It doesn't use `window.require` at all (and so, no problem that I know of).

---

Or there's this (which I'm not using):

- [Electron and React integration done right](https://patrickpassarella.com/blog/creating-electron-react-app)

It talks about using `window.require`

> We need to import the ipcRenderer module using `window.require`, because we want to require the electron during runtime from the node environment, rather than the one used during compilation by webpack. link to the github issue [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300).

I don't know why it wants to require at runtime instead of during compilation.

It links to this issue, which is Closed and has 93 comments:

- [Requiring electron outside of main.js causes a TypeError](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300)